# Mudar Cor da DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Galera, 
   Preciso de uma ajuda, já pesquisei mas não encontrei,
   Gostaria de saber como posso fazer pra mudar a cor do item selecionado na DataGrid.
   Exemplo: Quando tenho uma linha na datagrid e clico em cima ela fica selecionado com a cor azul, gostaria de trocar essa cor.
   Alguém consegue me dar uma dica.

Comment: mostre o código

Answer (score 2):

Uma possibilidade é ter uma propriedade no objeto que está listando para fazer isso:

```
public virtual int BackgroundId { get; set; }
```

No evento de click você pode alterar o valor dessa variável para diferenciá-la das demais:

```
seuObjeto.BackgroundId = 1;
```

No XAML, dentro do datagrid cria-se um datatrigger:

```
<DataGrid.CellStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding BackgroundId}" Value="1">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding BackgroundId}" Value="2">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
</DataGrid.CellStyle>
```

A partir de agora os itens que tiverem essa propriedade alterada também terão seu background alterado. No exemplo para 1 ou 2, mas você pode definir quantos quiser no datatrigger